# Adding a physics body to a drawn line

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, line, game-physics

I am working on an iOS app with sprite kit where I draw a line in the following way:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint positionInScene = [touch locationInNode:self];

    pathToDraw = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, positionInScene.x, positionInScene.y);

    lineNode = [SKShapeNode node];
    lineNode.path = pathToDraw;
    lineNode.strokeColor = [SKColor blackColor];
    lineNode.lineWidth = 5.0f;
    [self addChild:lineNode];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint positionInScene = [touch locationInNode:self];
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, positionInScene.x, positionInScene.y);
    lineNode.path = pathToDraw;
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPathRelease(pathToDraw);
}
```

This is working exactly how I want it to, but I am not sure where to begin with my next step.

I want to create a physics body for the line that I have just drawn.

I would preferable to this in the touchesEnded method.

How can I add a physics body to the line regardless of its width?

My best guess is to track all the points, then do some math to figure out a path along the edge of the line, then add the physics body.

Is there a better way to do this before I dive into my approach?

Comment: look at using [ [SKPhysicsBody edgeChainFromPath:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKPhysicsBody/bodyWithEdgeChainFromPath:) ]